# How to Access a specific group within CollectionViewSource.View.Groups

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, collectionviewsource

I have a .NET [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) in my WPF view model and its doing some custom grouping using a GroupDescription based upon enum property and sorting using a SortDescription tied to a simple double property. This CollectionViewSource is used in one view and doing exactly what I need it to do there but I'm trying to augment the view with a sister view that will detail some summary statistics for the individual groups comprising my collection view source.

Based upon my random walks through intellisense the only approach I've managed to discern involves iterating over the groups and dynamically casting them to CollectionViewGroup and checking the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.name(v=vs.100).aspx) property.

I'd like to know if there is any way of selecting a *specific* subgroup at a high enough level without having to evaluate unknown groups in whatever unknown order they assume according to the source data? I'm trying to avoid having to conduct the grouping operations myself with the source data just so I can plug them into my sister views. I would presume piggybacking off of the CollectionViewSource's groups would be the optimal approach.